# Sentence case for titles in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, capitalization

I'd like to have the titles of articles in Biblatex in sentence case (first word capitialized, the rest lowercase, override with {}) as is the default in Bibtex.

I tried:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase{#1}}
```

However it also makes converts other fields into sentence case, such as the booktile:

```
[Pai99] P Paillier. “ Public-key cryptosystems based on composite degree residuosity classes”. Eurocrypt. 1999
```

I'd like:

```
[Pai99] P Paillier. “ Public-key cryptosystems based on composite degree residuosity classes”. EUROCRYPT. 1999
```

(This assumes that booktitle is EUROCRYPT in the .bib file)

Is there anyway to do this, short of adding {} to each booktitle entry?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The format definition

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase{#1}}
```

makes [*all* titles in sentence case](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20335/4483), which isn't what you want. Titles need to be printed according to both the entry and field types. For example, with the `title` field we need to handle `@article` and `@book` entries differently. With `@inproceedings` entries we need to handle the `title` and `booktitle` fields differently.

To do this we can redefine the `title` bibmacro to print the `title` field of `@article` and any `@in*` entry type in sentence case. Taking the original definition found in `biblatex.def`:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{sentencecase}{\MakeSentenceCase{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
  \ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{title}\AND\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
    {}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifentrytype{article}\OR\ifentrytype{inbook}%
      \OR\ifentrytype{incollection}\OR\ifentrytype{inproceedings}%
      \OR\ifentrytype{inreference}}
      {\printtext[title]{%
        \printfield[sentencecase]{title}%
        \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
        \printfield[sentencecase]{subtitle}}}%
      {\printtext[title]{%
        \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
        \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
        \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}}%
     \newunit}%
  \printfield{titleaddon}}
```

Alternatively we can identify book-like entries directly and apply sentence casing to everything else. This is trickier because many more types qualify as book-like references and titles for these sources are printed by more than just one macro. In `biblatex.def` these include: `title`, `booktitle`, `maintitle`, `journal`, `periodical` and `issue`. To avoid redefining all of these, you can redefine the `titlecase` format instead.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeTitleCase{#1}}

\newrobustcmd{\MakeTitleCase}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifcurrentfield{booktitle}\OR\ifcurrentfield{booksubtitle}%
    \OR\ifcurrentfield{maintitle}\OR\ifcurrentfield{mainsubtitle}%
    \OR\ifcurrentfield{journaltitle}\OR\ifcurrentfield{journalsubtitle}%
    \OR\ifcurrentfield{issuetitle}\OR\ifcurrentfield{issuesubtitle}%
    \OR\ifentrytype{book}\OR\ifentrytype{mvbook}\OR\ifentrytype{bookinbook}%
    \OR\ifentrytype{booklet}\OR\ifentrytype{suppbook}%
    \OR\ifentrytype{collection}\OR\ifentrytype{mvcollection}%
    \OR\ifentrytype{suppcollection}\OR\ifentrytype{manual}%
    \OR\ifentrytype{periodical}\OR\ifentrytype{suppperiodical}%
    \OR\ifentrytype{proceedings}\OR\ifentrytype{mvproceedings}%
    \OR\ifentrytype{reference}\OR\ifentrytype{mvreference}%
    \OR\ifentrytype{report}\OR\ifentrytype{thesis}}
    {#1}
    {\MakeSentenceCase{#1}}}
```

> *edit* by [@moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe): **Note that the `biblatex` documentation recommends to use the starred form `\MakeSentenceCase*`** instead of `\MakeSentenceCase`. The starred macro considers the language of the entry (as given in the `langid` field, or failing that assuming the current language) and only applies sentence case where it is appropriate (by default only for English-language publications).

Comment: That does not seem to do what I want. That limits the application of sentence case to articles (as opposed to inproceedings, techreport, etc.). What I want is within an article bibtex entry (and other types), to have it applied to title but not to booktitle.

Comment: @PulpSpy I expanded my answer to multiple types. Sentence casing for *everything* but book titles is possible by redefining the title macro as I've done here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16467/4483. I could elaborate using another edit to my answer.

Comment: Right I could see how to expand it to other types. What I am interested in is the second thing: within a given type (say article), have the title in SentenceCase and have the booktitle with no formatting (although I have no need to limit it to articles).

Comment: @PulpSpy Ah, I think I see now. The `booktitle` field doesn't apply to the `article` entry type. So your question had me thinking in terms of casing different types, not different titles within the same entry. I should have examined your example more closely.

Comment: Yeah I could have been clearer too: I was thinking inproceedings but saying article. Anyways, the declaration works exactly the way I want. Thank you!!!

Comment: For future reference, if anyone attempts the solution above (which is great!), and gets a mysterious error when compiling, be aware of math formulas in the bib-file: \MakeSentenceCase does not handle maths like "$\alpha$", unless you write it within curly brackets (i.e., "{$\alpha$}").

Comment: @MarkusJalsenius -- thank you -- for anyone else, the error was a "missing { inserted" on my `\end{document}` line on the pdflatex run after biber had been run.

Comment: Does this work with biblatex-chicago? I'm trying to get this to work in my document but it's having no effect whatsoever--not sure if it's the package, or where I'm putting the code, or what...

Comment: How would we do the first approach for techreport's titles as well?

Answer (score 7):

[`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext) introduces new field formats for a finer control over title casing. Where standard `biblatex` has the format `titlecase` that applies to all title-like fields alike, `biblatex-ext` has

- `titlecase:title`
- `titlecase:booktitle`
- `titlecase:maintitle`
- `titlecase:maintitle`
- `titlecase:journaltitle`
- `titlecase:issuetitle`

which apply only to the specific field in their name. As usual, these field formats can be defined per type. See pp. 21-22 of the [`biblatex-ext` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext.pdf). (Of course `biblatex-ext` still supports the standard `titlecase` format.)

If you only want the titles of entries whose titles are in quotation marks in sentence case, then use

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {titlecase:title}{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{springer,weinberg,doody,maron,pines}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Weinberg, Steven (1967). ‘A model of leptons’. In: Phys. Rev. Lett. 19, pp. 1264–1266.]

Comment: Thanks @moewe! This should have been built into biblatex by default!