Reformatting a Paragraph Consisting Entirely of Capital Letters
Consider the code:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\parskip 15pt

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\large

THIS IS A PARAGRAPH WHOSE SENTENCES CONTAIN WORDS COMPRISED OF CAPITAL LETTERS. THIS IS A PARAGRAPH WHOSE SENTENCES CONTAIN WORDS COMPRISED OF CAPITAL LETTERS. THIS IS A PARAGRAPH WHOSE SENTENCES CONTAIN WORDS COMPRISED OF CAPITAL LETTERS.

\lowercase{THIS IS A PARAGRAPH WHOSE SENTENCES CONTAIN WORDS COMPRISED OF CAPITAL LETTERS. THIS IS A PARAGRAPH WHOSE SENTENCES CONTAIN WORDS COMPRISED OF CAPITAL LETTERS. THIS IS A PARAGRAPH WHOSE SENTENCES CONTAIN WORDS COMPRISED OF CAPITAL LETTERS.}
\end{document}

with output

The first paragraph contains words which are all capitalized.
By applying the command \lowercase to the first paragraph, I get the second paragraph which uncapitalizes every letter.
What I really want to do is leave the first letter of every word in the first paragraph capitalized, while rendering all the rest of the letters lowercase, so that I have:
``This Is A Paragraph Whose Sentences Contain ...''
I thought perhaps, that if I loaded the titlecaps package, the following trick might work:

\titlecap{\lowercase{THIS IS A PARAGRAPH WHOSE SENTENCES CONTAIN WORDS COMPRISED OF CAPITAL LETTERS. THIS IS A PARAGRAPH...}}

But alas, for some reason, it didn't.
QUESTION: Is there a command which might accomplish what I want to do? If not, how may I accomplish this?
Thank you.

never use \lowercase on general text only on specific code strings over which you have full control, such as ascii filenames, it will destroy any accented characters if using pdftex, typically breaking the utf-8 encoding so making it impossible to decode the text at all, not just failing to lowercase correctly.

If this is for titles please see my comments under cfr's  answer.

It is not for titles. I have a large block of capitalized text copied in my actual document that I would like to avoid retyping.

@DavidCarlisle Thank you for your comment on \lowercase.

Doesn't your editor do that? In mine, I can just highlight the text and turn it into lowercase, uppercase or titlecase (though with the caveats @yannisl mentioned i.e 'titlecase' in the LaTeX 3 sense rather than real titlecase).

I am doing the typesetting for this project.

\MakeTitlecase{} makes the first letter uppercase, but it does not alter anything beyond the first letter. There is nothing equivalent, as far as I'm aware, for changing the first letters of subsequent words at the document level. However, there is a function in the expl3 programming layer which we can use for such a purpose. Moreover, if we first make the argument lowercase, it will also work for uppercase and mixed-case arguments.
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \MakeTitlecaseAll { +m }
{
  \exp_args:Ne \text_titlecase_all:n { \text_lowercase:n { #1 } }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\parskip 15pt

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\large

\MakeTitlecaseAll{THIS IS A PARAGRAPH WHOSE SENTENCES CONTAIN WORDS COMPRISED OF CAPITAL LETTERS. THIS IS A PARAGRAPH WHOSE SENTENCES CONTAIN WORDS COMPRISED OF CAPITAL LETTERS. THIS IS A PARAGRAPH WHOSE SENTENCES CONTAIN WORDS COMPRISED OF CAPITAL LETTERS.}

\MakeTitlecaseAll{this is a paragraph whose sentences contain words comprised of capital letters. this is a paragraph whose sentences contain words comprised of capital letters. this is a paragraph whose sentences contain words comprised of capital letters.}

\MakeTitlecase{ŵy}
\MakeTitlecaseAll{ŵy siân tŷ â  î i}

\MakeLowercase{THIS IS A PARAGRAPH WHOSE SENTENCES CONTAIN WORDS COMPRISED OF CAPITAL LETTERS. THIS IS A PARAGRAPH WHOSE SENTENCES CONTAIN WORDS COMPRISED OF CAPITAL LETTERS. THIS IS A PARAGRAPH WHOSE SENTENCES CONTAIN WORDS COMPRISED OF CAPITAL LETTERS.}
\end{document}


I shall delete this when somebody tells me how stupid it is.

That is the correct answer, don't delete it:-)

Code is correct, but to do it properly real title casing for editorial purposes is hard. Need to incorporate language rules and also a list of abbreviations  and prepositions. Had some old code and a question here, and Wills helped me to partially solve it at the time.

continuing.... Some examples   \clist_gset:Nn \title_words_not_capitalized_en   {a, an, the, at, by, for, in, of, on, to, up, and, as, but,    it, or, nor, do, for, this, be, A, An, The, At, By, For, ... , abrreviations {iTunes, A.B.C.` ...  1) Split the sequence at spaces. 2) ucfirst first word and last, within check for exceptions, otherwise lowercase...

@yannisl That's essentially how chronos does it and also how I did it in an earlier version of this answer. But that isn't what this question asked for and the version I have doesn't work correctly with accented characters. Do you have a link to your question here?

9 years ago!  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246091/capitalization-in-headings-a-latex3-approach/246148#246148   I did rewrite the code as well at the time, but obviously now l3 and lua have more capabilities.

Wow. Mine is ... er ... rather more basic. It doesn't work at all with accents. It does work with a list of exceptions which should be lower case. It also has to work in the context of a tikzpicture, though the use does mean I can rule out e.g. paragraph breaks because there are some things you can't put in a node anyway. (I just used regex which, of course, is fairly limited for text.)

One could patch titlecaps for this situation:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlecaps,xpatch}
\def\explowerchar#1{%
  \ifcase\numexpr`#1-`A\relax
   a\or b\or c\or d\or e\or f\or g\or h\or i\or j\or k\or l\or m\or
   n\or o\or p\or q\or r\or s\or t\or u\or v\or w\or x\or y\or z\else
   #1\fi
}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\title@string}{\@thestring#2}{\@thestring\explowerchar{#2}}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\titlecap{THIS IS A PARAGRAPH WHOSE SENTENCES CONTAIN WORDS COMPRISED OF CAPITAL LETTERS. THIS IS A PARAGRAPH...}
\end{document}


